# Make paired delimiter with prefix for Re and Im

Tags: math-mode, macros, mathtools

I'm trying to make a new command for something like this:

```
\operatorname{Re}\left\lbrace\num{1+2i}\right\rbrace
```

Because I'm using the `mathtools` package already I tried to do something like this:
(And I have to undefine the previous `\Re` and `\Im` commands, because they are ugly and this command should be obviously called `\Re` and `\Im`.)

```
\let\Re\undefined
\let\Im\undefined
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\Re{\operatorname{Re}\lbrace}{\rbrace}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\Im{\operatorname{Im}\lbrace}{\rbrace}
```

This will work, but will also spit put many errors. Like: `Missing { inserted. \end{align}` and so on.

Then I thought: Yes, this is probably, because the font can not scale (and shouldn't), like the `\lbrace` and `\rbrace`. And I tried something like this:

```
\let\Re\undefined
\let\Im\undefined
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\braces{\lbrace}{\rbrace}
\newcommand{\Re}{1}{\operatorname{Re}\braces*{#1}}
\newcommand{\Im}{1}{\operatorname{Im}\braces*{#1}}
```

But this will produce:

> Missing $ inserted. \newcommand{\Re}{1}{\operatorname{Re}
>
> Missing \begin{document}. \newcommand{\Re}{1}{\operatorname{Re}

Inserting `\ensuremath` or something like that doesn't help much.

Last try:

```
\let\Re\undefined
\let\Im\undefined
\newcommand{\Re}{1}{\operatorname{Re}\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
\newcommand{\Im}{1}{\operatorname{Im}\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
```

> Missing $ inserted. \newcommand{\Re}{1}{\operatorname{Re}
>
> Missing \begin{document}. \newcommand{\Re}{1}{\operatorname{Re}
>
> You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode. ...nd{\Re}{1}{\operatorname{Re}\left\lbrace #

It can't be this hard to make something like this work, or can it? I really don't know what I should try next, or what am I even doing wrong.

Comment: why do you want `\left` and `\right` with 1+2i? you would get better spacing with `(1+2i)` than with `\left(1+2i\right)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the incorrect syntax for `\newcommand`.

```
\newcommand{\Re}{1}
```

should be

```
\newcommand{\Re}[1]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP`from `mathtools`. It will define  `\Re`and `\Im` commands, which have a star version (adds a pair of implicit `\left` `\right` in front of the delimiters), but they also accept an optional argument among `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` and `\Bigg`, which adds a pair oof implicit `\bigl` `\bigr`, &c.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} %
\let\Re\undefined
\let\Im\undefined
 \DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\Re[1]{\operatorname{Re}}{\lbrace}{\rbrace}{}{#1}
 \DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\Im[1]{\operatorname{Im}}{\lbrace}{\rbrace}{}{#1}

\begin{document}

   \[ \Re*{\frac{z-1}{z + 1}}\qquad \Im[\Big]{\frac{z-1}{z + 1}} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't operator name be better for Re and Im, then `2\Re` looks right again. Re and Im are math operators after all

Comment: @daleif: You're right. I didn't think of testing this. I've fixed the code. Thanks!